# Relational Database join between two tables having unknown number of intermediate tables

Tags: sql, relational-database

I have a large database that I want to set up a generalized query method for subtables (or a join between subtables). However, the tables I'm interested in are sub-tables of a parent table that is an unknown number of tables deep of relationships from that parent table, depending on the table I'm querying.

Is there a means by which your can get SQL to automatically join all of the interim tables between the two tables of interest? Or narrow a query to only a subset of parent table?

For example this set of relationships:
Folder_Table->System_Table->Items_Table->Items_Class->Items_attributes->Items_Methods->Method_Data->Method_History

I want to be able to generically do searches or joins of any of the sub-tables, where the results are for only a single folder of Folder_table, without having to do a series of explicit joins to X table levels deep... which would significantly increase the complexity of building generic queries interfaces at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not.

What you're asking for is the famous "figure out what I want done and do it" function, which would be the golden panacea of programming languages or databases.

SQL is explicit. You need to specify the path by explicitly listing the tables to join and how to join them.

Now, could you make such a function for your specific case? Sure. You would build into it the knowledge of either your specific table structures, or the way to obtain the information needed to automatically find the path between table A and table B. However, there is no such built-in function that already exists, just waiting for you to use it. So if you want such a function, you're going to have to write it yourself.

Bonus questions:

- What if there's multiple paths between A and B?

Comment: In my defense, I don't think this falls into a "golden panacea" category. I'm just looking from a modern programming language paradigm which expects an interpreted language like SQL to have introspection. With introspection, it should be able to understand the chain of relationships between A and B, without explicitly calling them... perhaps with the exception of complex situations involving multiple parallel loops (but honestly can't why this couldn't be resolved).